# "Unsupported image object", using Python

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am building a character identifier from an image using Tesseract and Python.

This is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"

img = cv2.imread("bigsleep.jpg")
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

cv2.imshow("Img", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
print(text)
```

I am getting the following error while executing this program

```
TypeError: Unsupported image object
```

Can anyone solve this issue

Comment: You tried to  send full path of image?

Comment: On a separate note, tesseract expects image in RGB format while the cv2 uses BGR format. You should convert BGR to RGB format before passing the array to tessract